# Parse simple math equation with 2 operands and 1 operator in the middle

Tags: c

I only need to handle the following equations.

9-8

5222/12

322*445

7878+7

However, when I enter `8+9` as the inpurt.
The console only shows  `8.000000+`
It seems not handling the last operand.

I guest the I didn't have this branch correctly `else if(isOperator(*endTemp))`

Any idea? or direction?

```
static double getUserInputValues() {
    double values[NUM_OF_USER_INPUT_VALUES];
    while (1) {
        errno = 0;
        char temp[257];
        char operator;
        fgets(temp, 256, stdin);
        char *str = strtok(temp, " ");

        int cnt = 0;
        while (str != NULL && cnt < NUM_OF_USER_INPUT_VALUES) {
            char *endTemp;
            double val = strtod(str, &endTemp);
            printf("%f", val);
            if (*endTemp == 0 || *endTemp == '\n') {
                values[cnt] = val;
                cnt++;
                str = strtok(NULL, " ");
            } else if(isOperator(*endTemp)){
                operator = *endTemp;
                printf("%c", operator);
                str = strtok(NULL, " ");
            }
            else {
                errno = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return getReturnValue(values, operator);;
}


static bool isOperator(char ch){
    switch(ch){
        case '+':
            return 1;
        case '-':
            return 1;
        case '*':
            return 1;
        case '/':
            return 1;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I begin, I highly suggest that you learn how to use a debugger, since these kinds of things are exactly the reason why they exist. Knowing how to debug a problem effectively, is an indispensable tool in a programmer's toolkit.

Anyway,
strtod will try to parse a floating point number from a string, placing the rest of what it did not parse in the pointer given in the second argument.

strtok will break a string into tokens.
In your case, you are delimiting using a space, and so the first token you will get from the input "8+9", will be "8+9", as there are no spaces in this input.

A call to strtod will then parse out the 8 from this token, storing the rest of the string "+9" in endTemp.

You are only extracting the operator in your code, after which you proceed to discard the remaining contents and take the next token.

```
operator = *endTemp; // endTemp == "+9" at this point
                     // so *endTemp == '+'.
printf("%c", operator);
str = strtok(NULL, " "); // discard current token (9 is not handled).
```

As you can see, you are not handling the remaining number.

A simple fix would be the following:

```
operator = *endTemp; // endTemp == "+9" at this point
                     // so *endTemp == '+'.
printf("%c", operator);
str = endTemp + 1;   // str == "9" now.
```